# Partial template specialisation without rewriting the class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am in the process of writing a matrix class, which is a template class:

```
template <class T, int height, int width>
```

and I want to write member function that counts the determinant of the matrix. How do I declare this function only for square matrices without writing the whole separate template class for square matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your matrix class is templated on the `height` and `width`, a square matrix is a matrix with those template parameters equal. You can have such a class as a parameter easily with the same `N` for the second and third template argument:

```
template <class T, int N>
auto get_det(const Matrix<T, N, N>& mat) -> float;
```

---

In your case that would be the simplest solution. You can however do it also with `enable_if`, but in this specific case it is overkill. You may however apply it to some other more complex solutions:

```
template <class T, int H, int W>
auto get_det(const Matrix<T, H, W>& mat) -> std::enable_if_t<H == W, float>;
```

Check [enable_if documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [C++ Idioms/enable-if](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/enable-if) out if you want to learn more about SFINAE and `enable_if`

---

If you want a **method**, unfortunately, things aren't that easy. You can specialize just one method from a class, but you cannot partial specialize it. There is a trick however to work around it:

```
template <class T, int H, int W>
struct Matrix {

  template <int N = H, int M = W>
  auto get_det() const -> std::enable_if_t<N == M, float> { return 2.4f; }
};
```

You can test it like this:

```
Matrix<int, 2, 3> not_square;
Matrix<int, 2, 2> square;

// error error: no matching member function for call to 'get_det'
// note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with N = 2, M = 3]
//not_square.get_det();

//OK:
square.get_det();
```

Here `get_det` needs to be templated, because `enbale_if` must operate on the member template parameters. Otherwise, if it would operate on the class template parameters (`enable_if_t<H == W>`) it would disable the entire class, not just the member.

A minor disadvantage is that you could explicitly specialize the method, thus allowing it to be called on a non-square matrix. But that is something that simply it shouldn't be done and it usually isn't:

```
// No compilation error:
not_square.get_det<2,2>();
```

---

Another trick for a method is to use a free function:

```
template <class T, int H, int W>
struct Matrix;

namespace detail {
template <class T, int N>
auto get_det(const Matrix<T, N, N>&) -> float { return 3.5; }
}

template <class T, int H, int W>
struct Matrix { 
  auto get_det2() const -> float { return detail::get_det(*this); }
};
```

I honestly didn't think that would work, but both clang and gcc behave. Still not 100% sure it is ok. Will investigate when I have the time.

Comment: _Explain_ your proposed solution. Don't just dump code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In this case I think the code is self-explanatory. Other that to show that it can be done this way, I sincerely don't see what I can tell more.

Comment: For starters, you can explain how the code works: maybe it's "self-explanatory" to you but if it were "self-explanatory" to the OP then they'd probably have simply written it themselves. Also, you can tell why you think this is the best solution and what less optimal possibilities the OP may wish to consider under various circumstances. Y'know, all the juicy detail that always goes into a good Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I hate you :))

Comment: Wasn't the OP looking for a member function?

Comment: what does -> mean in method signature?

Comment: @RomaValcer `auto foo() -> int` is the trailing return type declaration introduced in `C++11`. It is equivalent (with one exception) with `int foo()`

Comment: Good ones. The second solution is indeed OK, but it's basically equivalent to implementing the `get_det2` member directly and adding a `static_assert(H == W)` in its body (nicer error message too). However, you will get into trouble if explicitly instantiating the `Matrix` template for non-square matrices: an explicit instantiation definition will instantiate the definition of `get_det2` and trigger a compile error, both with the helper function and the `static_assert`. You need to carefully work around that by moving the function definition after the explicit instantiation; not very nice.

Answer (score 3):

It might not always be viable, but I think the simplest (or at least easiest to read/understand) solution is to write a common base class that contains all the default methods. The actual template only inherits this class and is empty otherwise, whereas the parital (or full) specializations add their additional mehtods:

```
template<class T, size_t M, size_t N>
struct BaseMatrix{
        T& operator()(size_t r, size_t c) {
            return  _e[r*N+c];
        }

    protected:
        BaseMatrix() =default;
        ~BaseMatrix() = default;

    private:
        T _e[M*N];     
};

template<class T, size_t M, size_t N>
struct Matrix: BaseMatrix<T,M,N> {
};

template<class T, size_t M>
struct Matrix<M,M>: BaseMatrix<T,M,M> {   
    T det(){return 42;}
};
```